# Is $K[X_1,X_2,...]$ a G-domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Recall that an integral domain $D$ with quotient field $K$ is called a Goldman domain (or G-domain) if $K$ is finitely generated ring over $D$.

Is $K[X_1,X_2,...]$ a G-domain, where $K$ is a field ?

Comment: Yes, thanks for your remark .

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldman_domain) and the reference to  Kaplanski.

Comment: $K[X_1,X_2,...]$ is not a Noetherian ring.

Comment: Sorry, I am too tired, it seems...I thought, it was only finite many variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that if $R$ is an integral domain then the polynomial ring $R[X]$ is not a Goldman domain; see [Proposition 12.5](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf).

We can then view

$$ K[X_1,X_2,\ldots] $$

as

$$K[X_2,\dots][X_1].$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer